# VB.net Graphics not drawing to screen

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a hangman game and i cant get my dashes to draw on the screen.

```
Public Class Form1

Public lines() As String= IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\axfonath14\Desktop\words_alpha.txt")
Dim thisArray As String() = lines.ToArray
Public word As String = thisArray(CInt(Int((thisArray.Length * Rnd()) + 1)))
Public g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
Public dash As Image = My.Resources.dash 
Public x As Integer = 1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.Text = word
    For Each c As Char In word
        x += 1
        g.DrawImage(dash, 125 + (100 * x), 100)
    Next
    Label2.Text = x
End Sub

End Class
```

when i run this code it runs through the loop and changes the label to the amount of letters but it just wont draw anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never, EVER call `CreateGraphics`.  Lazy people do so without explanation in examples and tutorials but it is never appropriate in a real application.  ALWAYS do your drawing in the `Paint` event handler of the control you want to draw on.  In your case, get rid of that `g` field altogether, move your drawing code to the `Paint` event handler of the form and use the `Graphics` object that it provides:

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    For Each c As Char In word
        x += 1
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(dash, 125 + (100 * x), 100)
    Next
End Sub
```

That way, your drawing gets restored each time the form gets erased and repainted, which can be often and will be after the `Load` event handler completes.

If you want to change what gets drawn then you need to store the appropriate data in fields that can then be accessed from the `Paint` event handler.  To force a repaint, call `Invalidate` on the form or control whose `Paint` event you're handling.

Answer (score 0):

You're grabbing the graphics context before the form has initialized. Move your initialization code to the actual constructor, after the `InitializeComponent()` method is called.